# Why can't intermediate filaments be used as tracks by motor proteins?

Tags: cell-signaling, cytoskeleton

A motor protein like kinesin-1 cannot use an IF as a track because it lacks polarity.

Can someone elaborate on this answer?

Comment: Just a guess: the IF doesn't have directionality. It would be like a single-lane, but two-way road.

Answer (score 1):

Polarity essentially means a plus end (growing/polymerising) and a minus end (depolymerising). Look at microtubule (MT) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microtubule). So molecules such as Kinesin-1 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinesin) use the hetero-dimeric nature of MT (alpha and beta subunits) and its polarity to orient themselves and move directionally along MT in an energy dependent manner.